# Building a querystring based on list column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am  on SPD 2010. I want to set a column value for a custom list based on another column value. Basically, I am trying to build a URL with query-string parameters.

This URL will open a page with a Query String Filter Context Web Part.

Is there a way to dynamically build such a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is either calculated or computed fields, depending on which use case you have. Either way its not really javascript related.

You can accomplish your needs by simply editing the XSLT for the view used in your custom list.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I will try to find out how to do that. (However, I am scared of declaratives, and feel code-based or js solution is always simpler, if there is one)

Comment: Found out some solution based on dear JavaScript. http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-window-or-not/

Comment: glad to hear everything worked out, but just note that your solution was not based on computed columns. Just wanted to make sure it was clarrified if you search in the future so it might help you